# MVC5 view name mobile version

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using the .tablet and .phone extensions for my tablet and phone views. 
With MVC4 I used to create them without any problem but with MVC5 I have the error:

> The name is invalid because it has invalid characters

I'm trying to create a view with name: List.tablet

(I can't show you the image because I have not enough reputation).

I've checked that it happens with MVC5 and not MVC4, both with visual studio 2012.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using the Add -> View **directly**? This doesn't work, but if you go to Add -> New Item and then choose View or Layout page they both work in any combination.